# OS X doesn't allow me to change the input source for passwords boxes

Tags: macos, language

In my OS X El Capitan I can only use en-US input for all password boxes (other input methods are not available). But most of my password are in Russian.

How can I change the input source in OS X El Capitan?

Comment: [Since you already asked this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241785/change-language-in-os-x-el-capitan-in-login-menu), let's keep it to just that one thread.

Comment: @JMY1000 The question you've linked is about the login screen, this one here about password boxes. The answer may not be the same.

Comment: @patrix Ah, thanks. That wasn't clear before the edit by klanomath.